# What is the significance of "G12" in the evangelism strategy "G12 Vision"?

Tags: evangelism, etymology

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=G12_Vision&oldid=855484105):

> The **G12 Vision** is a Christian evangelism and discipleship strategy established by Pastor César Castellanos, the founder of International Charismatic Mission Church.

However, it doesn't explain the origin of the name. What is the significance of "G12" in the evangelism strategy "G12 Vision"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [GotQuestions.org](https://www.gotquestions.org/g12-vision.html) G12 stands for Government of 12.

> Castellanos believed that God spoke to him in a vision, laying out what He desired the Church do in response to the end times. This vision was the “government of 12” principle, a hierarchal pyramid scheme of discipleship and authority. He proposed that because Israel had 12 tribes, and Christ had 12 disciples, the Church needed to base their structure on this governmental model and become a cell-church.
>
> The G12 model works this way: a pastor trains 12 people to be cell leaders. These cell leaders are each responsible for discipling 12 others in a cell group, usually with a minimum number coming from the community and not from within the church they attend. After a specified time, and after certain strict requirements are met, these cell members then become leaders themselves, and start their own cells. Thus, the membership of the church is multiplied, and the message of the Gospel is taken into the community.

Comment: Isn't GotQuestions.org a site similar to Stack Exchange? If so, can we find a better source for the answer?

Comment: @Thunderforge It's not user editable, I think it's more similar to CARM and other sites that give one (or a few) people's views. No doubt a better source could be found, but I didn't find it yet ;)